# Как работает EditorWindow.OnGUI() в Unity 3D?

Tags: javascript, unity3d

Не понимаю как работает отрисовка полей и получение значений, введенных пользователем в Unity 3D.

Вот пример из документации:

```
    // Editor Script that clones the selected GameObject a number of times.

    class EditorGUILayoutIntField extends EditorWindow {

        var clones : int = 1;

        @MenuItem("Examples/Clone Object")
        static function Init() {
            var window = GetWindow(EditorGUILayoutIntField);
            window.Show();
        }

        function OnGUI() {
            clones = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Number of clones:", clones);
            if(GUILayout.Button("Clone!"))
                for(var i = 0; i < clones; i++)
                    Instantiate(Selection.activeGameObject, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
```

Не понятно как работает вот эта строчка:

```
clones = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Number of clones:", clones);
```

Она вроде как и отрисовывает поле и возвращает значение, введенное пользователем. Объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, подобные поля в `EditorGUI` возвращают значение, введенное пользователем.

Логически все просто понять: для того, чтобы установить значение полю, достаточно ему передать какое-то значение из переменной или написать вручную. Однако, в таком случае, по факту, это поле будет `read-only`, т.к. через инспектор нельзя будет никаким образом изменить значение в этом поле. Что и логично, ведь `OnGUI` работает несколько раз в секунду, а в поле мы можем написать `EditorGUILayout.IntField("Number of clones:", 100500);`, в результате чего несколько раз в секунду перерисовывается поле с константным значением.

Для чего пишут так: `clones = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Number of clones:", clones);`? Чтобы сделать, так сказать сообщение между переменной и значением, которое ввел пользователь.
Получается некий бесконечный круг:

- В поле заносится значение переменной.
- Пользователь меняет значение в поле
- Это значение передается обратно в переменную, чтобы:
- После очередного обновления `OnGUI` значение этой самой переменной попало опять в `IntField`
  Тем самым мы сможем влиять на переменную через поле. А поле отображать реальное значение переменной на данный момент

Если не хотите, чтобы значение переменно через поле изменялось просто пишите
`EditorGUILayout.IntField("Number of clones:", clones);` без `clones =`

Может логичным показаться вопрос, почему не сделать передачу по ссылке? Но не все значения так пишутся. Некоторые не возвращают значение в переменную, чтоб  поле оставалось как раз `read-only` и при этом значение переменной нельзя было через поле изменить.

Может показаться что разрабам было бы логичнее сделать что-то типа того `EditorGUILayout.IntField("Number of clones:", clones, true/false);` где true/false задает передавать по значение ссылке или нет, но, думаю, это сложнее по логике реализовать, чем просто вернуть значение. Возможно еще по каким-то причинам.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но имелось в виду как EditorGUILayout.IntField("Number of clones:", clones) узнает из какого поля нужно забрать значение. Т.е. как unity понимает из какого именно контрола нужно забрать значение clones, ведь я могу написать так: clones = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Number of clones:", clones); clones1 = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Number of clones:", clones1); и т.д.

Comment: Ну так это будет ДВА совсем разных интовых поля, одно которое берет значение из одной переменной, а другое из другой. То, что вы написали `Number of clones` и там и там - не значит, что это одно поле на две переменные..Это всего лишь надпись. А если написать 100500 раз `EditorGUILayout.IntField` появится 100500 таких полей, с привязкой к своему значению, на каком-то уровне им присваивается свой идентификатор и все... как в `css` и `html`

Comment: Это понятно. Но когда  вызывается EditorGUILayout.IntField("Number of clones:", clones), как unity передает идентификатор поля? Т.е. что поле идентифицирует, когда происходит идентификация и как она пропагируется через множественные вызова OnGUI?

Comment: Не понимаю что вы хотите. Зачем вам внутренняя логика юнити? Она закрыта в классах библиотек, чтоб вы не лезли туда и не задумывались об этом. Если вы думаете об этом как решение для своего приложения, то, видимо, что-то не так делаете, что хотите до этого добраться. Если вы хотите добраться специально намеренно прям до внутренностей - разрезайте всё через `Reflection` и смотрите на внутреннее устройство.......что вы в итоге хотите получить? непонимаю

Comment: Мне просто очень интересно как это работает. Попробую разобраться через рефлексию.

Answer (score 0):

`OnGUI` исполняется несколько раз за кадр, в зависимости от события, то ли это отрисовка контрола, то ли обработка действий от пользователя. Поэтому эта функция которая рисует контрол в окне если полезете копаться через `Reflection` будет выглядеть не просто.
Видимо отсюда и такой вид вызова, что при обработке разных событий она должна вести себя по разному.

Answer (score 0):

Каждый вызов OnGUI Unity обрабатывает отдельно и создает для каждого вызова отдельный idspace, чтобы идентификаторы контролов не путались. При каждом вызове EditorGuiLayout.IntField() идентификатор контрола получается при помощи вызова GUIUtility.GetControlID(), который однозначно определяет контрол по контенту, позиции и порядковому номеру.
[Документация Unity::GUIUtility.GetControlID](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUIUtility.GetControlID.html)